# Indicate number of items in meta review queues when displayed from main review page

Tags: feature-request, review

When viewing the review page on main, each queue has a number next to it indicating how many items remain. At the end of the list of queues is a link to the meta review page, but this gives no indication of whether there are any meta items to review:

[image: Example view of main review page]

Since many sites have very few reviews in the meta queue, clicking through to find out if there are meta reviews usually gives a negative result, giving an incentive to stop checking. If there was a number, simply showing the total number of meta reviews (the sum of the individual meta review queues), then on those occasions when a meta review appears, it would be picked up more quickly as no one would need to check the meta review page to notice it.

Comment: To the upvoters after this was closed as a duplicate: I hope you're following the link to the original request and upvoting that - that's the one that will make the difference. Upvoting this duplicate isn't going to help.